# Why can't AKS pull the image from ACR?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I have an AKS cluster and an ACR registry in Azure. The cluster contains several Windows nodes where a WindowsServerCore based service is deployed. The image is in ACR, but for some reason I can't get it to pull the image, I always get the imagePullBackOff error.

I have tried all methods, attach the ACR in AKS, through a Secret (both using ACR admin and through a new Service Entity), but there is no way, everything fails. The strange thing is that when I do a `kubectl describe pod` it doesn't return me anything concrete, only the imagepull error, nothing else. It does not indicate authentication error...

```
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----    ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal  BackOff  85s (x1341 over 5h6m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "myacr.azurecr.io/so99:860"
```

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score -1):

you need to integrate AKS with ACR via **AcrPull** permission.

If you have existing cluster use this command:

```
az aks update -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr <acr-name>
```

To create new cluster with integration use:

```
az aks create -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr <acr-name>
```

Comment: I already did that, it doesn't work. In fact I did it at the time of creating the cluster and it didn't work, I did it again later and it didn't work either. 

The entity with AcrPull permissions is created correctly but I always get the imagepull error when I deploy the service.

Comment: are you using "System Assigned" or "User Assigned" Identity for the AKS ?

Comment: @PhilipWelz When you attach between AKS and ACR, as indicated by Kamil, Azure creates a "User-assigned Managed Identity", at least that's how I see it in Access Control -> Role assignments in ACR

Comment: @Toni Miguel López Did you try to pull some Linux images from ACR on Linux node to eliminate that this is not a permission issue just Windows node issue? Maybe the image is incompatible with Windows node and give strange imagePullBackOff error.